# how to validate an X509Certificate chain using a given Certificate

Tags: security

I have an trusted Certificate given by user (may be self-signed). I want to use that certificate to validate https server certificate chain.

I found there was code example like:
[Validate X.509 certificate against CA in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629473/validate-x-509-certificate-agains-concrete-ca-java)
which only validating if last certificate certs[0] is signed by given certificate.

Following link is using CertPathValidator to validate the certificate.
[Java X509 Certificate parsing and validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043376/java-x509-certificate-parsing-and-validating)

Which example should I follow? I suppose if any certificate in certificate chain is signed by given certificate, the validation is passed, is it right?

Comment: I'd say that neither link is complete. Validation of the certificate is a complex procedure which involves validation of all certificates in the certificate chain, sending OCSP requests and using CRLs for each certificate, and also validating certificates of OCSP responses and CRLs. We have implemented an advanced certificate validation class in our SecureBlackbox product, and this class does all I mentioned.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You may authenticate server cert client-side or client cert server-side. You may not use client cert to validate server cert. These are the two independent chains normally.

Comment: I wants to develop a https client to connect to a https server. I would like my user to give a certificate which he trusts, and I use this certificate to validate server ceritificate chain.